# Check if a objekt is an array

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I am currently trying to take apart a objekt with logic like this

```
public String toString(Object x) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    if(i > 10000) {
        throw new StackOverflowError("The Deserilesation of an objekt has overflowen");
    }
    i++;
    if(x instanceof String) {
        return String.valueOf(x);
    }else if(x instanceof Integer) {
        return String.valueOf(x);
    }else if(x instanceof Boolean) {
        return String.valueOf(x);
    }else if(x instanceof Long) {
        return String.valueOf(x);
    }else if(x instanceof Float) {
        return String.valueOf(x);   
    }else if(x instanceof Double){
        return String.valueOf(x);   
    }else if(x instanceof Byte){
        return String.valueOf(x);   
    }else if(x instanceof Character){
        return String.valueOf(x);   
    }else {
        String toreturn = "{";
        for(Field f : x.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                toreturn += f.getName() + ":"+ toString(f.get(x)) + " ";
            }catch (NullPointerException e) {
                toreturn += f.getName() + ":Null ";
                }
            }
            toreturn += "}";
    return toreturn;
}
```

but if there is a `int[]` then i will get the standert tostring like 00000@000000, my question how can i deteckt that i have an array, i tryed `if(x instanceof Array)` but there is not array class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to know the class name of the array use the following syntax:-
**array_name.getClass().getName()**. To check whether the object is array or not, use the **isArray()** method as follows:- **array_name.getClass().isArray()**. For more clarification, go through the following example:-

```
class Sample{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int arr[] = {1,2,3};
        System.out.println(arr.getClass().isArray());
    }
}
```

i hope it is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, for the quick answer

Comment: Welcome and go ahead!

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
x instanceof int[]
```

But more generally:

```
x.getClass().isArray()
```

Comment: @YCL_L Do you mean "beat"?